# Both start index and end index are out of range but the substring method still works in Java

Tags: java

I tried the code `"a".substring(1, 1)` and it didn't throw an exception. But the start index is 1, which is larger than 0, and because the start index is inclusive, shouldn't it throw an exception?

Similarly, `"".substring(0, 0)` doesn't crash either, even though 0 should be out of range for an empty string.

Comment: What does the documentation for `String.substring` say, exactly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Acording to the documentation of the method:

> Throws:
>   IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object.

The length of your string is 1 and not 0, so it doens't throw and exception.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the substring method returns a string (substring) whose length is equal to (end-start), param values: passed in your method.

*If end-start = 0*, It would return an emptry string. Please see the source code of **ORACLE JDK1.7**

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
        if (beginIndex < 0) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
       }
        if (endIndex > count) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex);
        }
        if (beginIndex > endIndex) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex - beginIndex);
        }
        return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == count)) ? this :
            new String(offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value);
    }
```

It would raise an **IndexOutOfBoundsException** only when this happens:

*

> if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length
>   of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

*